# Convert EC PRIVATE KEY from .pem into WIF

Tags: private-key, electrum, private-key-import, wallet-import-format, openssl

I have a openssl generated private key in the following form:

```
$ cat priv.pem
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BgUrgQQACg==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIDTijUe0yc3orw5+hElM2WZPWWawO6yTymJZagaStSxIoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAE81+mTl3Pyzy41kCg8xgnV3lokrYJ/iUAGda0JUpx99aExBk1kD9Heera
5ndWARwUTa6T1Cfi7c1U6Nf81IEAQQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can i convert this (preferably using bash/Perl/python) into a WIF that can be imported into (preferably) Electrum? Also Electrum confuses me a bit, it says

```
WIF keys are typed in Electrum, based on script type.

A few examples:
p2pkh:KxZ...->
1Dck
```

What does this mean? Wallet import format does not say anything about typing

Answer (score 3):

> How can i convert this (preferably using bash/Perl/python) into a WIF that can be imported into (preferably) Electrum?

OpenSSL .pem files contain base-64 encoding of the values encoded using DER. In case of private keys they use PKCS#8 explained in [RFC5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208). To extract the key itself, you first have to decode the base-64 string and get the key out by reading the DER encoding (the posted example is missing 1 byte since the sequence length is 0x74 but the remaining bytes that come after it is 0x73 bytes). If you want to use OpenSSL itself, try using this command:

```
openssl pkey -in priv.pem -out priv.key
```

This should give you the key bytes. Now you have to convert them to WIF (base-58 with checksum). Use your favorite bitcoin library (I don't have any python suggestion but there are many you could find on GitHub) that has byte-to-Wif functions.

> What does this mean? Wallet import format does not say anything about typing

Your **one** private key gives you **one** public key that could be used in both compressed and uncompressed form in **many** different output scripts which then you will see as a different type of address (P2PKH script -> address starting with 1; P2WPKH script -> address starting with bc1; ...). So when the private key is imported in a wallet, the wallet either has to look for all the output script types (like what Bitcoin-Core does) or ask the user to explicitly include the script type (which is what Electrum does).
In other words when you import a private key in Electrum with `p2pkh:<key>` the wallet only checks the address starting with 1 (legacy or base58) and when import it with `p2wpkh:<key>` it only checks the address starting with bc1 (native SegWit or bech32) and so on.

As a side note, there is [BIP-0178](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0178.mediawiki) that proposed extending WIFs to address this and also Electrum briefly used a different way similar to this BIP but stopped because of incompatibility with other clients.

Comment: DER encoding contains more than just the key itself, it includes things like the curve parameters. WIF just encodes the private key itself. So after decoding the base64 string, you still have to extract the actual private key. That's just a matter of looking up how DER encoding works and then finding the private key.

Comment: OpenSSL supports 8 privatekey PEM formats, only two of them PKCS8, and the example in the Q is not PKCS8 format, it is SEC1. (And as you note, corrupted.) To convert to DER, you need `pkey ... -outform der` or `ec ... -outform der`. But you don't really need to; any language that can compute base58check or similar can decode base64 and select bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can import the private key generated by OpenSSL to Electrum, Bitcoin Core, Mycelium and some other Bitcoin wallets after converstion to the Wallet Import Format.

There is the bash script for the converstion: https://gist.github.com/GregTonoski/438992249df6e4bd613f9758421ff38a

Usage example:

```
$ openssl ec -in private_key.openssl.pem -text | grep -A 3 'priv:' | tail -n 3 | tr -d -c [:xdigit:] | xargs bash private_key_into_bitcoin_wif.sh > private_key_bitcoin.wif
```

The resulting text in the private_key_bitcoin.wif is accepted by Bitcoin wallets.

Side note: in case of Bitcoin Core the import works only for the non-descriptor type of wallet which is created like that: `$ bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name="your_wallet_name" descriptors=false` (the default setting is: `descriptors=true`).

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way, use python

```py
from bit import Key, PrivateKey, PrivateKeyTestnet

# Import PEM file
key = Key.from_pem('path/to/pem_file/here')

# Export to wif

WifFormat = Key.to_wif()

print(WifFormat)
```